# how to combine the result from differentviews to IQueryable<T>

Tags: wpf, linq

i have a list of PlanItems bind to telerik RadGrid and have two views retrieves the result.Each view get different data so how can i get that data into IQueryable

```
public class PlanItems
{
    public int Id{get; set;}   
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string HV { get; set; }
    public string StNumber { get; set; }
    public string LDNumber { get; set; }

    public string MSId { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }

}

 I have 2 different views vw_Boys ,vw_Girls and Student Entity
```

first i got boys_Id and Girls_Id from student Entity

```
    public IQuerable<PlanItems> GetAllStudents()
        {
        var Id = from v in context.Student
                  .Include("SBoy") 
                  .Include("SGirl")                    
                  where v.CreatedBy_Id == user.Id
                  select v;
        var temp = unp.Select(a=>a.SBoy.boys_Id).Distinct();
        var temp1 = unp.Select(a => a.SGirl.girls_Id).Distinct();

           var vwboys = from nv in context.vw_boys
                 where(temp.Contains(nv.SId))
                 select nv;

        var vwgirls= from nv in context.vw_girls
                        where (temp1.Contains(nv.GId))
                        select nv;

         var Boysresult = from n in vwboys
                     select new PlanItems
                     {
                         Id = n.SId,
                         Name = n.Name,
                         HV = n.HV,
                         StNumber = n.SNumber,
                         LDNumber = n.LineNumber,
                         MSId = n.MasterId,
                         CreatedBy = n.USerName,
                        Type = n.SubjectType
                     };

        var GirlsResult = from n in vwgirls
                          select new UnplannedItems
                          {
                           Id = n.GiId,
                         Name = n.Name,
                         HV = n.GV,
                         StNumber = n.SujNumber,
                         LDNumber = n.Lid,
                         MSId = n.MasterId,
                         CreatedBy = n.USerName,
                        Type = n.SubjectType
                          };  

          }
           my telerikGrid sample

     <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="StudentID" IsReadOnly="True"    DataMemberBinding="{Binding ID, Mdde=OneWay}" />
```

how can i return the result from above method..how can i combine the result to one.

Comment: why are you separating them because you are doing same thing to both of them ?

Comment: I dont know how to do..can we make join those views and retrieve data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it something like this.

Add a new property to you class like this. Because you might have to seperate the boys from the girls in a other case:

```
public class PlanItems
{
    public int Id{get; set;}   
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string HV { get; set; }
    public string StNumber { get; set; }
    public string LDNumber { get; set; }

    public string MSId { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
        //new property
    public bool IsUnplanned { get; set; }
}
```

The use a concat between them like this:

```
var result= ( 
        from n in vwboys
        select new PlanItems
        {
            Id = n.SId,
            Name = n.Name,
            HV = n.HV,
            StNumber = n.SNumber,
            LDNumber = n.LineNumber,
            MSId = n.MasterId,
            CreatedBy = n.USerName,
            Type = n.SubjectType,
            IsUnplanned=false
        }
    ).Concat
    (
        from n in vwgirls
        select new PlanItems
        {
            Id = n.GiId,
            Name = n.Name,
            HV = n.GV,
            StNumber = n.SujNumber,
            LDNumber = n.Lid,
            MSId = n.MasterId,
            CreatedBy = n.USerName,
            Type = n.SubjectType,
            IsUnplanned=true
        }
    );
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi,.i need to get MSId from another method as views  doesn't contain this column..GetMSID(int Id) ..and this method need the Id n.SId and n.GiId..how to do this?

Comment: Is it a database function or a local function?

Answer (score 1):

You can union 2 different IQueryable using union extension method :

[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb156049.aspx)'s an example

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert in wpf, but looking at the solution I think you can use a parent class for both Boys and Girls and then add to a list of that class.

lets say both Boy and Girl classes are inherited from Person class, then create

```
List<Person> personList = new List<Person>()
```

and add Boys and Girls into this list.

I am not sure whether this is the solution you need